# How to obtain value from inner request. Function return undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to get a quiz from table quizzes and after obtaining it 
trying to an array of answers from table questions. But it doesn't work

I send questionDto(JSON) to **this.add** method, where the question I've already
added in the table and need to add answers and

```
var question = require('../models/question');

function Quiz() {
  this.getById = function(quizId,res) {
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      con.query('select * from quizes where `id` = ? ', quizId, 
  function(err, result) {
        con.release();
        result.questions = question.getAllByQuizId(quizId);
        res.send(result);
      });
    });
  };
```

**question.getAllByQuizId(quizId);** has to return an array of questions. Here is an implementation

```
function Question() {

  this.getAllByQuizId = function(quizId) {
    return connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      return con.query('select * from questions where `quizId` = ? ', quizId, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;

        con.release();

        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)));
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
      });
    });
  };
```

console.log() returns applicable value but the function return undefined

I have wasted hours to tackle. But still can't :(

Comment: From where you are calling 'question.getAllByQuizId(quizId);'?

Comment: From the first chunk which i provided (function Quiz())

result.questions = question.getAllByQuizId(quizId);

Comment: I have updated the below. Please have a look at the latest and modify your code accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a callback to handle this instead of 'return' as it has a asynchronous block in the function.

```
var question = require('../models/question');

function Quiz() {
  this.getById = function(quizId,res) {
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      con.query('select * from quizes where `id` = ? ', quizId, 
  function(err, result) {
        con.release();
        question.getAllByQuizId(quizId, function(err, data){
           if(err) {
              throw err;
           } else {
              result.questions = data;
              res.send(result);
           }
        });
      });
    });
  };

function Question() {

  this.getAllByQuizId = function(quizId, callback) {
     connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
       con.query('select * from questions where `quizId` = ? ', quizId, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) callback(err);

        con.release();

        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)));
        callback(null, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)));
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: **quizId is not defined** -> here question.getAllByQuizId(quizId

Comment: It seems you are passing this where quiz.getById is called. Please check why it's coming as undefined.

Comment: I have updated as in your original code. Please check this

Comment: I needed to replace question.getAllByQuizId(quizId, function(err, data){ ... } into the Quiz. Now it works, Thank you!

Comment: Please let me know if you need anything.

Comment: How I can find you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127972/discussion-between-denis-evseev-and-aruna).